# Why apt-get trying to install latest version instead of installing specified needed dependencies version?

Tags: dependencies, apt, package-management

I am using **Artifactory** as my own debian packages repo.

I have a package 'hello' that I set `Depends: world (= 1.0.0.0), apple (= 3.0.0.0)` in it's **control** file.

And when I try to install that package: `apt-get install hello`
I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
onecgf : Depends: world (= 1.0.0.0) but 1.0.0.2 is to be installed
          Depends: apple (= 3.0.0.0) but 3.0.0.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package
```

**Why is it trying to install (world=1.0.0.2 & apple=3.0.0.4) when it knows it needs to install older versions?**

It works only if I execute: `apt-get install hello world=1.0.0.0 apple=3.0.0.0`

**Why do I need to tell apt-get what versions to install?**

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350199/73892 (outside stackoverflow)